# grunt-express: Configuration with socket.io ignores http bases

Tags: javascript, node.js, socket.io, gruntjs, grunt-express

I have an weird issue while I am trying to setup my project to use *grunt-express*, I am currently trying to configure *socket.io* to work which sort of breaks normal asset routing.

I have two modes which I use to run my server, **dev** and **prod** and based on those modes I will serve my files from different locations respectively.

Relevant stuff in **Gruntfile.js**:

```
express: {
  options: {
    server: "app.js",
    port: 3000,
    hostname: "localhost"
  },
  dev: {
    options: {
      debug: true,
      bases: "dev"
    }
  },
  prod: {
    options: {
      bases: "public"
    }
  }
}, .. etc ..
```

I am using this: **app.js:**

```
/**
 * Module dependencies
 *
 */
var express = require("express"),
  packageJson = require("./package.json"),
  app = express(),
  path = require('path'),
  httpServer = require("http").createServer(app),
  io = require("socket.io").listen(httpServer);

/**
 * Express
 *
 */
app.configure(function() {

  app.use(express.compress());
  app.set("views", __dirname + "/app/views");
  app.set("view engine", "jade");
  app.use(express.favicon(__dirname + "/public/img/favicon.ico"));
  app.use(express.logger("dev"));
  app.use(express.bodyParser());
  app.use(express.methodOverride());
  app.use(app.router);

  /**
   * 404 page
   *
   */
  app.use(function(req, res) {

    res.status(404).render("404");

  });

});

/**
 * Socket.io
 *
 */
io.configure(function() {

  io.set("log level", 2);

});

/**
 * Routes
 *
 */
require("./app/routes")(app);

/**
 * Export
 *
 */
exports = module.exports = httpServer;

// Adding necessary use() method for returnable httpServer instance
exports.use = function() {
  app.use.apply(app, arguments);
};
```

With setup like this, if I run my server in **dev** mode happens the following (**bases is ignored**, but `http://localhost:3000/socket.io/socket.io.js` works!:

```
socket.io.js  - 200 - FOUND
main.css      - 404 - NOT FOUND
require.js    - 404 - NOT FOUND
```

However, if I change my **app.js** configure section to add for example **dev** route manually (same as bases), everything works perfectly:

```
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'dev')));

socket.io.js  - 200 - FOUND
main.css      - 200 - FOUND
require.js    - 200 - FOUND
etc.js        - 200 - FOUND
```

The reason why I wan't bases to work is because it will be less hacky and those were meant to be used like that, they will work if I remove *socket.io* stuff completely.

Any hints? thnx!

Answer (score -1):

Per the [server](https://github.com/blai/grunt-express#server) spec in the README, you don't want to use listen() in your app, so that's one issue I see.  I also see you're using debug, [which was deprecated](https://github.com/blai/grunt-express#debug-warn-no-longer-availabe-in-10).

Comment: Yes, but what configuration of the Gruntfile.js and app.js would make it work as expected?